# What can stop infinite error producing/error handling loop in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, error-handling

I have an Asp.net MVC project and an internal server error has occurred, handled by **Application_Error** method in **Global.asax.cs**.

It made a `Server.TransferRequest(path, false);` to the action that returns a view that didn't exist and caused another internal error. This error was also caught and handled in **Global.asax.cs**. So the infinite loop of handling and producing errors had started.

The result is that it has produced over 200 iterations and then stopped.

Why did it stop to produce the errors? How was the loop terminated?

Does anyone have any ideas about this? I think this situation must be handled by IIS (7.5 version) but I cannot figure out. Or maybe there is limit for call stack depth?

Thanks.

Comment: IIS would stop this after a specific range.

Comment: Specific range of what? I am thinking about stackoverflow exception, but i had no such error in log.

Comment: Specific number of requests.

Comment: Does `TransferRequest` init new request? I think it just change the way of handling request, redirecting to another resource in application.